# VSCode setting up a JSON Schema reference to a private GitHub repository

Tags: json, github, visual-studio-code, schema

I'm currently using Visual Studio Code 1.66.2, with Github Repositories and GitHub Pull Requests and Issues extensions installed.  I can pull, push, and so forth to and from my private repository from VSCode without a problem.

However, when writing a JSON document involving a schema import, for example:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://github.com/[company]/[thing]/blob/master/validation/jsonSchema/eor/1-0-0.json",
}
```

VSCode claims:

> Unable to load schema from
> 'https://github.com/[company]/[thing]/blob/master/validation/jsonSchema/eor/1-0-0.json':
> Not Found. The requested location could not be found.

I assume this is due to the repository being private and VSCode not being able to access it, but given that I've authorized it for GitHub access, I haven't been able to figure out how to let it see and reference the JSON schema file.

I've tried adding the following to VSCode's settings.json:

```
"http.proxy": "http://[username]:[personal access token]@github.com/[company]/[thing].git",
"http.proxyAuthorization": null,
"http.proxyStrictSSL": true
```

But that just results in endless "Loading..." for the json file in question.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.